# SFMC Email Studio Bounced Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, email-studio

Emails are sent to customers, at some point the customer soft bounced and then they eventually hard bounced. Email Studio will not send them anymore emails. Because this contact had originally  successfully received emails, they are in All Subscribers and All Contacts. How is a hard bounced contact treated when it comes to the Contact Limit in SFMC? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start here with this article: [Contact Definition and Count Determination in Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5)

> Marketing Cloud can store a contact record in one of several different locations.
>   Contact Builder All Contacts list
>   Email Studio All Subscribers list
>   Populations, formerly known as root data extensions, including these examples:
>   Contacts involved in custom activities via Journey Builder
>   Contacts added via queries, filters, data extracts, or other data-intensive operations

If the contact exists on All Subscriber they count